# Object has no method 'live' - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').live('click', function(e){
        alert('delete');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
<a href='#' id='_1' class='delete'>Delete</a>
```

Gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

I just don't see the problem?

Comment: jQuery version, browser?

Comment: It's removed in jQuery 1.9 and no longer supported.

Comment: You should also modify your jquery.js script to be /1.9.0/ rather than /1/ so that these kinds of problems don't happen anymore and so that you get better caching.

Comment: @adeneo it is deprecated, not removed. shouldn't be throwing errors because of that.

Comment: @jbabey It is literally removed in 1.9, not depreciated. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`.live()` is a deprecated function (from 1.7+) and removed completely from jQuery 1.9+.

You can instead use `.on()` or `.bind()` methods:

http://api.jquery.com/on/ 
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Not just deprecated, but removed as of jQuery 1.9

Comment: But on/bind do not have the functionality of live, the other elements added after do not fire those events. live was useful for that.

Answer (score 13):

1. If the call to `.live()` is inside your own code, just change it to `.on()` using the rules shown at http://api.jquery.com/live.
2. If the code is in a third-party jQuery plugin, use the jQuery Migrate plugin to restore `.live()` until the author updates their plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme.
3. In production sites, do not use URLs that reference the "latest" version of jQuery such as http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js or http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js since they will automatically update when a new version of jQuery is released and your site will suddenly break if it is not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery 1.7+ use `on(...)` instead of `live(...)`.
Check this: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

There is one scenario when neither .on(), nor .bind() won't work: when the element does not exist when the event handler is being added. And this was what live() did.

Comment: It's true, but you may rebind the event after the new element is created.

Comment: This is *not* true. The `.on()` method can do everything `.live()` can do, just read the `.live()` documentation to see how.

Comment: This is why you delegate with `.on()` to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

See on http://api.jquery.com/live/

old

```
$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate("a.offsite", "click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });  // jQuery 1.4.3+
```

new

```
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 1):

[use .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function(e){
        alert('delete');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery migrate plugin (use that) ....... it will resolve the issue

ASP.NET MVC ajax-unobtrusive + jQuery 1.9 
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13220