# Clear Rails form after submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I want to clear text_form after message submitting. This is my form:

```
<%= form_for :chat, :html => {:id => 'send_form'}, :url => {:controller => :chat, 
       :action => :chat_save }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:text, :class => "text_field round") %>
    <%= f.submit(:class => 'button round') %>           
<% end %>
```

I`ve done, like in this topic: [Clear Rails remote form after submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053039/clear-rails-remote-form-after-submitting). First I try this in my js file:

```
$('#send_form').submit(function() {
$('#chat_text').val('');
});
```

the text_field become clear, but it send a blank line. Then I try this one, it sends message now, but text_field doesn`t become empty:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#send_form").live("ajax:complete", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
        $('#chat_text').val('');
    });
}
```

May be some libraries missed? Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 3):

if you're ok with waiting for a reply from the server, you can create a `.js.erb` file that will be executed after the request. inferring from the form action, create a file called `chat_save.js.erb` in `app/views/chat` and add

```
$('#chat_text').val('');
```

Comment: it`s amazing!!! Thank you very much, it works grate! I spend 15 hours for finding solution.