# Clear link form after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to clear my form after I submit a link but I can't seem to get it to work.

**links/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Link.new], :remote => true, html: {id: "new_link"} do |f| %>
```

**links/create.js.erb**

```
$('.button').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question: @question})  %>");
$('#linkpartial').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink', locals: {question: @question})  %>"); 
$('#linkform').reset("<%= j (render :partial => 'links/form', locals: {question: @question})  %>");
$("#new_link").bind("ajax:complete", function(event,xhr,status){
$('.createcomment').val('');
}
```

**controllers/links_controller.rb**

```
def create 
respond_to do |format|
 if @link.save
  format.html 
  format.js
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053039/clear-rails-remote-form-after-submitting) seems like a good solution - Adds an event handler for the ajax:complete event:

```
$("#new_link").bind("ajax:complete", function(event,xhr,status){
  $('#id_of_your_field').val('');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, now when I click submit the links partial isn't updated either.  I'll update my answer with the full js file.